# How do I get an iterable range from an N-dimensional container without copying?

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have a nested structure, say some class that contains some other classes:

```
struct Obj
{
  std::vector<T> mVector; // T is large
};

std::vector<Obj> myVector;
```

I want to use some existing function, let's call it `std::find_if`, to find occurrences of `T` that match some criterion, etc. Many Standard Library functions (`std::find_if` included) require iterable ranges as inputs, so simply passing `myVector` iterators into these functions will cause the rows, not the elements, to be traversed.

Performance is also a concern so I don't want to have to reconstruct an entire vector of pointers or, worse, copy the objects themselves just in order to run these functions across the elements.

Having used `boost::adaptors` for various useful tasks such as filtering or indirecting containers without reconstructing them first, I figure I basically want to be able to do something like this:

```
auto myRange = boost::adaptors::nested(myVector, functor);
```

Where functor is some lambda that yanks nested ranges out of each row in my matrix, something like this:

```
auto functor = [](auto& it) { return boost::iterator_range(it.begin(), it.end(); }
```

Of course, `boost::adaptors::nested` doesn't exist. So how can I flatten this 2D array without copying `Obj` and without creating another flattened container first? The answer should be reasonably efficient while minimising the amount of code and boilerplate.

Comment: Start with a flat array. You cannot flatten something that's not flat.

Comment: With any random-accessable container, you can always do `i * nColumns + j` with 2D and so on. You can wrap this with a function or `operator()`. See how the matrix classes are built with C++.

Comment: You can create an iterator that stores both an outer iterator and an inner iterator. Whenever you do ++, it acts on the inner iterator, tests if it has reached end(), and in that case ++ the outer iterator and reinitialize the inner one to begin(). There is some cost to doing that. This can be applied recursively (inner or outer may already be nested).

Comment: @xiver77 I have updated the question to clarify that the _2D_ _vector_ example was just an illustration. My structure is actually more complex.

Comment: @MarcGlisse that's pretty much what I'm after; can I do this without implementing all the boilerplate myself? I was surprised that `boost::adaptors` didn't seem to already have a solution, so I was hoping I'd missed something.

Comment: "*You cannot flatten something that's not flat*" - that's a bit absolute, isn't it?

Comment: It isn't that bad, using boost helpers the boilerplate is pretty much limited to implementing the increment function.

Comment: But it may be easier to write a specialized find_if function for your structure, with a plain for loop. I think it would be cool if compilers implemented exceptions in a clever enough way that it made sense to use for_each for your task, using an exception for the early exit when the value is found.

Comment: You have many options including using templates or runtime branching to achieve what you want. But if you really need performance, my opinion is not to use nested data structures at all. They give you bad locality by default, causing cache misses. High end CPUs with large caches often hide this cost, but with a not-so-great CPU you will easily get a visible performance loss.

Comment: Think how you'd write a similar code in C. Without those whole bunch of abstraction mechanisms available, you'll often find a clean and direct way to solve your problem. It's really my personal opinion that I don't like boost style C++ code. But that's me and still it's you writing your code.

Comment: @xiver77 cache locality _might_ be poor with nested structures, but it really depends on the application. I don't think it makes sense to generalise with such a broad question. Let's assume for the purpose of this question that a nested structure is the correct layout.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is indeed to write an adaptor. It will need to keep track of the iterator in the outer container, and an iterator within the inner container.

Here is an example implementation, that only supports `forward_iterator` semantics, and `const` access — I'll leave a more complete implementation to you!

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>

template <typename V>
struct flat_view {
    V &v;

    typedef typename V::value_type inner_type;
    typedef typename inner_type::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename inner_type::reference reference;
    typedef typename inner_type::const_reference const_reference;

    struct const_iterator {
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename inner_type::const_iterator>::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename inner_type::const_iterator>::pointer pointer;
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename inner_type::const_iterator>::reference reference;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;

        typename inner_type::const_iterator i,i_end;
        typename V::const_iterator o,o_end;
        bool at_end;

        const_iterator(): at_end(true) {}
        const_iterator(typename V::const_iterator vb,typename V::const_iterator ve):
            o(vb), o_end(ve), at_end(vb==ve)
        {
            if (!at_end) {
                i=vb->begin();
                i_end=vb->end();
            }
        }

        const_iterator &operator++() {
            if (at_end) return *this;

            if (i!=i_end) ++i;
            while (!at_end && i==i_end) {
                if (++o==o_end)
                    at_end=true;
                else {
                    i=o->begin();
                    i_end=o->end();
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        const_iterator &operator++(int) {
            iterator c(*this);
            ++*this;
            return c;
        }

        bool operator==(const const_iterator &x) const {
            return (at_end && x.at_end) || (o==x.o && i==x.i);
        }

        bool operator!=(const const_iterator &x) const { return !(*this==x); }

        reference operator*() const { return *i; }
        pointer operator->() const { return &*i; }
    };

    typedef const_iterator iterator;

    explicit flat_view(V &v_): v(v_) {};

    iterator begin() const { return iterator(v.begin(),v.end()); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(); }

    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(v.begin(),v.end()); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return const_iterator(); }
};

template <typename V>
flat_view<V> make_flat_view(V &v) { return flat_view<V>(v); }
```

Quick demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v={
        {1,2,3,4},
        {},
        {10,9,8,7},
        {5,6}
    };

    auto f=make_flat_view(v);

    std::copy(f.begin(),f.end(),std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout," "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

produces:

```
1 2 3 4 10 9 8 7 5 6
```